# Get guid values with js and razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an Asp.Net mvc 3 project
I'm using razor, and need to generate guids in javascript

I was trying this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getNewGuid() {
        return '@Guid.NewGuid()';
    }
```

I'm using inside the click event for a button, but the second call to the function is returning the same value

What should I do for reevaluating the function with each call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The

```
@Guid.NewGuid()
```

is evaluated server-side when the page is rendered, so you will always get the same value.

You need a Javascript Guid library from somewhere.

Try the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript).

While you *could* make an Ajax call to the server, it's pretty pointless if all you're after is a unique value that could be generated far more efficiently client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller then use JSON to return a new Guid from the server. Then use $().ajax to get the value.

If you don't want to ask the server for one use the following answer
[Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)